# Conditional Routing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I've searched all over for this and can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Does anyone know how to setup a conditional route in CI? For example if the user is logged in then the `default_controller` should be `documents` but if not then it should be `home`. I've tried the obvious:

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in') ) {

    $route['default_controller'] = "documents";

} else {

    $route['default_controller'] = "home";

}
```

However this doesn't seem to work as I'm guessing the session isn't available until after the routes are set.

Comment: That's true, routes are loaded before the CI session sets up. One solution would be extending the `CI_Controller` to check the session and then calling different methods / loading different views.

Comment: I've added in place a redirect before the home/index method. However this results in the url becoming domain.com/documents. Is there a means of one controller firing a different controller's method?

Comment: There're two options, Either redirecting the logged-in or not logged-in user to a different URL (controller/method) or calling different methods of `MY_Controller` class for logged-in or not logged-in users to prevent the URL from changing. You could also do the second approach within your `home` controller.

Comment: post an extended answer from your comment, what you propose is the way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Controller with a session check that if user has logged in or not. Then you can **redirect()** the user accordingly.